# R seeds after a run; gbm;

Tags: r

This is the situation: 
1) I have a random sample, but want to know what seed generated the outcome. Is there a way I can find out? I know you can set it prior to the run, but how about after the experiment?
2) Has anyone tried replicating a gbm fit after a model fit has been created?
Thanks

Comment: (2) is not terribly related to (1) and should go in a separate question (with much more detail, and an example of what you're trying to do.)

Comment: @Dason [gbm](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gbm/index.html).

Comment: @Joran Thought that since both are related to random sampling, they could be linked. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like

```
mySeed <- set.seed(1234)
mySamp <- sample(1:1000, 10)
attr(mySamp, "seed") <- mySeed
```

Then you would always be able to retrieve the seed by using `attr(mySamp, "seed")`.  In the example, I'm modifying a vector of integers (`mySamp`), but the same logic applies to `gbm` objects.

Of course, in the example above, you need to set the seed beforehand if you are to retrieve it later.  Short of that or something close to it, I don't think that you can retrieve the seed after it's used.

Comment: Thanks, that will definitely help for next time. I haven't found any positive answer on retrieving the seed.